# MySQL Database won't work correctly after giving write permissions to xamppfiles in MacOS

Tags: mysql, ajax, database, xampp

I'm using XAMPP 7.4.29 and I've set "read and write" permission to "everyone" in the `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles` folder and all of its content, instead of the `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php` file.

If I didn't do that, phpMyAdmin wouldn't work.

The problem is that now the MySQL Database server won't launch if I press "start" via "manager-osx", so I have to use command `sudo /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/mysql.server start` to start the server. And it does start, but now it starts failing.

I get many errors in Ajax and, for instance, *weird* characters like *ñ, ú, á, í* stop being shown.

**Summery**:
Starting XAMPP MySQL Database server using Terminal command causes errors and bugs when accessing mysql database.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Do use paragraphs for stating your question. It makes it easier to read.

Comment: since you're using **MacOS** I will suggest removing XAMPP and using [Valet](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/valet), valet will not provide you phpmyadmin thing, so the phpmyadmin alternative will be [TablePlus](https://tableplus.com/) 
**Note: valet require knowledge of command lines**